# Virtual Box Have No IP Address error Show When Start Genymotion Device

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, dhcp

The responsible thing that is assigning dynamic IPs for you is called DHCP server so you have to enable it to resolve this issue.

Try the following:

Open VirtualBox's Preferences and under Network section, check the adapter named "vboxnet0" in "Host-Only Networks", double click on it and make sure to apply the following configuration there.

6- Double click on that name and apple the following configuration

Adapter Tab:

```
IPv4 Adapter: 192.168.65.1

IPV4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0
```

DHCP Server Tab:

```
Check "Enable Server"

HINT: THIS RESOLVES YOUR PROBLEM, BUT OTHERS IS REQUIRED TO AVOID OTHER PROBLEMS

Server Address: 192.168.65.100

Server Mask: 255.255.255.0

Lower Address Bound: 192.168.65.101

Higher Address Bound: 192.168.65.255
```

Note: make sure you don't have any other adapter with the same configuration that might cause conflicts .. revise all of adapters in that section, "Host-Only Networks" I mean, and delete the same ones there.

After Complete all instruction problem is not fix so please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got some solution for this. First Go to on Virtual Box and Check Above side Green color Button for start and Virtual Device and click on this then a screen occur when it will properly Show on your desktop. Now go to genymotion and Run Your Device proper function.
Try it and Thanks...